# How do I complete my assignment? I am lost

Tags: java

I am creating a program for school that requires me to input a year, and the program is supposed to tell me whether or not the year is a leap year.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner;
        System.out.print("---Leap Year---");
        System.out.print("\n\nEnter a year(whole number)");
        int year = keyboard.nextInt();
        public static boolean isLeapYear(int year)
    {
        boolean leapYear;
        if (year%4==0)
        System.out.print("year is not a leap year",year);
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure how to finish this, and frankly, I am pretty lost. Please help me.

Comment: You're very close!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We’re often pretty good at helping with small programs that don’t behave as they should. We need your help too, though: At least as important as the code is you tell us not only what it’s supposed to di (which you do tell us), but also how its observed behaviour differs. Are you getting any error messages? If so, paste it or them into the question. They can usually tell more experienced programmers a whole lot, making it a lot easier to help you. Also see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Fix compilation errors first by reading the compiler messages.

Comment: @armagedescu Asking about error messages from the compiler is 100 % OK. Only then the OP should make it clear that this was the intention of the question. And paste the error message/s into the question.

Comment: @OleV.V. Sometimes the developers deal with difficult compiler errors. But it is not the case. Otherwise the compiler would post automatically the code on stackoverflow for every trivial message.

Comment: @armagedescu One person’s *trivial* may be another person’s *incomprehensible*. Beginners’ questions are very welcome on Stack Overflow, and sorry to say, I might fear that your hint at the error messages being trivial — which they probably are to you and me — might be less than comforting for new users that don’t feel the same way.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this shall do the trick:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("---Leap Year---");
        System.out.print("\n\nEnter a year(whole number)");
        int year = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println(isLeapYear(year));

  }
  public static boolean isLeapYear(int year){
        boolean leapYear;
        if (year%4==0){
            return true;
         }else{
            return false;
          }
    }
}
```

You need to move the method outside of the main method, then call it and print the result. Furthermore, you need to tell the Scanner what it's reading.

**What's it doing?**

It's checking whether the year is divisible by 4. If it is, it will return **true**, which means that the year is a leap year. In all other cases, it will return **false**.

**What did you do wrong?**

Originally, your `isLeapYear()` method was defined to return a boolean. However, you didn't return anything. Printing doesn't return anything, so we must modify it to return a boolean.

**For example**, when I input `1964`, it returns:

```
true
```

Which means that 1964 is a leap year.